# Stopping the monitoring of the event log

Tags: c#, event-handling, event-log

I have some code that watches the event log for entry written events and executes a handler when one of these events happens. My question is if I want to stop watching the event log for entry written events how to I do that. Here is some code:

```
    if (//some condition where I want to watch event log//)
    {
          eventLog.Log = eventLogToMonitor;
          eventLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
          eventLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(EventLogHandler);

    }
    if (// some condition where I don't want to watch the event log anymore)
    {
         // turn off the event log monitoring
    }
```

So in a nutshell I guess my question is what code needs to go at **// turn off the event log monitoring** so that I am not monitoring the event log anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just unsubscribe from the event.

```
eventLog.EntryWritten -= EventLogHandler;
```

Read more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768(v=vs.80).aspx